# How can you you set a material-ui table to have uniform border thickness?

Tags: css, material-ui, frontend

My current implementation of a material UI table is to set a thickness of 1 pixel on all elements.
This causes a slightly thicker appearance in areas where two cells touch as opposed to the outer perimeter.

How can I get a uniform border width of 1px all around?

```
<Table border={1}>
    <colgroup>
        <col style={{width:'12.5%'}} />
        <col style={{width:'12.5%'}} />
        <col style={{width:'50%'}} />
        <col style={{width:'25%'}} /> 
    </colgroup>
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell>col1/TableCell>
        <TableCell>col2</TableCell>
        <TableCell>col3</TableCell>
        <TableCell>col4</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`border-collapse: collapse;` property should solve this issue.
The border-collapse property sets whether table borders should collapse into a single border or be separated as in standard HTML.
border-collapse property accepts separate|collapse|initial|inherit values.
Separate - each cell will display its own borders
Collapse - Borders are collapsed into a single border when possible 
Details in https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

Comment: @NicoHaase edited my answer with some explanation. Thanks!